# why is scons complaining "implicit dependency foo not found, needed by target bar" when foo exists?

Tags: scons

Scons is complaining

```
  implicit dependency foo not found, needed by target bar
```

foo is created in my SCons build flow, and then consumed in the creation of target bar.  After foo is created, SCons complains that it doesn't exist when it re-checks the dependencies before running bar.  Why is SCons caching the existence check for foo?

After I get the failure, if I remove .sconsign.dblite and rerun, SCons finds the file and keeps running.

Comment: it is difficult to help you without the scons script

Comment: The scons script is 4000 lines -- I won't inflict that upon you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was running with

```
SetOption('implicit_cache', 1)
```

When I comment out implicit caching, then this problem doesn't manifest.  This seems to be a bug...  shouldn't SCons re-check for the file if the implicit cache says the file doesn't exist?

Comment: +1, though I don't agree it's a bug. Documentation states it is a trade off. This option should not be enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.scons.org/doc/0.97/HTML/scons-user/x933.html the answer is to build once with --implicit-deps-changed to tell SCons to rescan.